# How are bitmaps scaled?

Tags: android, bitmap, uiimageview

I have two bitmaps.  Bitmap A is 257x257, and bitmap B is 255x255. The container they are both being placed in is 256x256.  How are bitmaps scaled?  In other words:

1) How can a bitmap be scaled by small values, such as 1 pixel?

2) What is the difference between scaling a bitmap up (placing B in the container) and scaling a bitmap down (placing A in the container)?

3) Is there a difference in cost between scaling in either direction by 1 pixel vs 100 pixels?

Comment: do you need code where you can compress image by pixels or wht??

Comment: I am only asking from a theoretical standpoint, no code is necessary although if it helps with the explanation that's a bonus!

Comment: google for scalling algorithms